# Fill range table from itab using LET

Tags: abap

I found this code for filling a range table (source is already offline):

```
DATA   lr_vkorg   TYPE RANGE OF vkorg.
TYPES: lr_range_t TYPE RANGE OF vkorg.

lr_vkorg = VALUE lr_range_t(
          LET s = 'I'
              o = 'EQ'
          IN sign   = s
             option = o
             ( low = '1100' )
             ( low = '1200' )
             ( low = '1300' )
             ( low = '1400' )
             ( low = '1500' )
).
```

But instead of doing something like this:

```
( low = '1' )
( low = '2' )
...
```

I want to fill it with the values of an internal table `['1', '2', ...]`.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

> Update: This is how I did it based on the answer:

```
DATA:
  lt_itab       TYPE TABLE OF string,
  lt_range_itab TYPE RANGE OF string
  .

APPEND '1'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '2'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '3'  TO lt_itab.
APPEND '4'  TO lt_itab.

lt_range_itab = VALUE #(
  FOR <ls_itab> IN lt_itab
  ( sign = 'I'
    option = 'EQ'
    low = <ls_itab> )
).
```

Comment: a range always consists of low high, a sign and a operator ... I think ranges will not solve whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @zYrEx I'm trying to fill a range table from an internal table with as less code as possible

Comment: ah okay. that was not clear from my perspective. is "['1', '2', ...]" a structure? just looks like an array or how is your internal table structured?

Comment: Not your question but the code you have found contains useless statements ; removing LET ... IN is a valid syntax : `lr_vkorg = VALUE lr_range_t( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' ( low = '1100' ) ( low = '1200' ) ... ).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare macro utilizing your declared structures like this:

```
DEFINE range.
 lr_vkorg = VALUE lr_range_t( BASE lr_vkorg ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = &1 ) ).
END-OF-DEFINITION.
```

And then fill your ranges with this one-liner:

```
range: '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600'.
```

If we speak about filling range from itab, use this statement:

```
lr_vkorg = VALUE #( FOR ls_vkorg IN gt_vkorg
                  ( sign = 'I'
                    option = 'EQ'
                    low = ls_vkorg-vkorg )
                  ).
```

Comment: But when I use itab, I don't need the top `( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = &1 )` anymore, right? Can I instead just do `DATA   lr_vkorg   TYPE RANGE OF vkorg.`?

Comment: `Can I instead just do DATA lr_vkorg TYPE RANGE OF vkorg?` No, you cannot. Macro and itab are two separate cases, macro fills only from literals. And **in both cases** you need declarations.

Answer (score 2):

```
lr_vkorg = VALUE # ( sign   = 'I'  option = 'EQ' ( low = '1100' ) ( low = '1200' )
             ( low = '1300' ) ( low = '1400' )   ( low = '1500' ) ).
```